# I am stuck and do not know what this means

Tags: next.js

I am getting this problem when I am running npm run dev in my NEXT JS 14.02 project

> Error: ETIMEDOUT: connection timed out, write] {   errno: -60,   code:
> 'ETIMEDOUT',   syscall: 'write' }  ⨯ uncaughtException: [Error:
> ETIMEDOUT: connection timed out, write] {   errno: -60,   code:
> 'ETIMEDOUT',   syscall: 'write' }  ⨯ uncaughtException: [Error:
> ETIMEDOUT: connection timed out, write] {   errno: -60,   code:
> 'ETIMEDOUT',   syscall: 'write' }  ✓ Compiled /not-found in 100ms (506
> modules)
>
> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error:
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat

I tried look at config packages

Comment: it seems like some kind of network issue, could you share your code for reviewing

Comment: try with your personal hotspot and disabling web filters, vpn etc.